# Using ScaleHeight in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following 'attempt at' a macro in PowerPoint which inserts a picture into the current slide:

```
Sub Insert_Traverse_2a()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture("\\nlamvfs00065\homes\nlkpec\newpic.png", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
        oPic.ScaleHeight(100, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft)
End Sub
```

However, the line with "ScaleHeight" gives a syntax error. From the documentation on

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.scaleheight(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.scaleheight%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

(I would like PowerPoint to not resize the image, since this causes a loss of resolution. Without the 'ScaleHeight' line, however, PowerPoint automatically resizes the image if it's bigger than the slide).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from the `ScaleHeight` method:

```
Sub Insert_Traverse_2a()
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Set oPic = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture("c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\logo.jpg", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
        oPic.ScaleHeight 100, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

Also, make sure you're reviewing the correct version of the documentation. What you linked to is for VB.net, not VBA for PowerPoint:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743874(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743874%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Indeed removing the parentheses made it work. (By the way, I found then that the factor "100" should actually be "1" to keep the image at its original size).

Comment: Yes, 100 would make it 100x it's original size :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Call` keyword

```
Call oPic.ScaleHeight(100, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft)
```